# Top 10 priorities in performance optimization of a complex Drupal site

Tags: performance

I read a lot about many ways to improve drupal site performance optimization, but I did not find a clear indication of the top 10 most relevant modifiations for optimizing the performance of a complex site.

I currently am working to optimize a very complex site that has completely grown out of hand and needs serious modification because current page load speed is about 4 to 6 seconds for authenticated users.
The website is mostly being used by authenticated users. The only access restriction is present through the Organic Groups module.

Current state:

- 90 node types
- 140 select boxes checked on the admin/modules page
- 63 Vocabularies
- 240 views (excluding the additional views displays)
- 30 rules,
- 50 rules components
- 130 node panel variants
- 10,000 lines of css (excluding the omega base theme and modules style
  sheets)

What is the most important to start with, in general?

Comment: _Top 10 priorities in performance optimisation_ is rather subjective, and _the most important_ is probably caching.

Comment: Might install New Relic and get some stats, check your network tab and see what is happening on each page request, use page speed insights for feedback also

Comment: Why would there be 10? Where does that number come from?

Comment: There, found you a 35-point one. 35 is better than 10 :)

Answer (score 1):

I won't talk about APC and other Apache optimization tricks.

In in experience:

1. Enable caching for Views and reduce use of Views
2. Enable Javascript and CSS compression
3. Minimize the modules. Disable unused ones. In production I disable as UI's .. the 
   following script will give you some help.
4. Most of bottleneck comes from Mysql. I suggest you optimize it and I found this [post useful](https://groups.drupal.org/node/289613).

**Disable User Interface Modules**

When not developing you can safely disable Field UI, Rules UI, Views UI, dblog etc. Also I'm sure but we should also be able to disable CKEditor/FCKEditors.

This is what I use in a script:

```
drush dis --yes admin_menu advanced_help backup_migrate content_type_overview  dashboard diff environment_indicator field_ui help module_filter rules_ui search term_merge update views_bulk_operations views_ui vppr  field_ui  rules_admin devel site_audit  drupalgeddon l10n_client taxonomy_manager dblog
```